# HttpListener "Connection Closed" in Browser when using SSL

Tags: c#, http, ssl

We have some custom http webservice build on `HttpListener` in .net 4.8.
This thing works fine on different customer systems, however on one of our new customers system, we have trouble getting SSL to work.

The problem is, that accessing a simple echo page (that just dumps the request into the output), modern browsers like firefox, chrome and edge get a connection reset, once the listener starts writing into the output stream.
Internet Explorer and WebRequests work without any issues.

Im pulling my hair out, all I could find is recommendations to reinstall IIS since this seems to be a known problem in old ASP.net Solutions. However we do not use IIS.

The next problem is, the customers IT is really restrictive and does not allow us to install tools like WireShark or Fiddler.

I dont know if there is any other possible combination of netsh commands to add the ssslcert, im certain by now that i treid everything.
We even used one of our own certificates, but no success.

**EDIT** It seems to be related to the fact, that the customer is using a Windows Server 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known problem in Server 2022

https://borncity.com/win/2022/10/22/fix-des-ssl-tls-verbindungsproblems-stand-der-sonderupdates-und-betroffene-anwendungen-21-10-2022/

Disabling TLS 1.3 via registry did the trick for us, as a workaround.